# How to uninstall virtualbox completely?

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, pacman

I installed virtualbox from the executable *run* file downloaded from its official website onto my Manajaro XFCE but now I can't seem to remove it. How to completely remove it from my system?

Comment: According to the documentation, it's `sudo ./VirtualBox.run uninstall`. What happens when you try that?

Comment: It gets removed, thank you. *facepalm*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the VirtualBox documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#install-linux-performing), the `VirtualBox.run` script takes an argument that should be either of the strings `install` or `uninstall`.

Using

```
sudo ./VirtualBox.run uninstall
```

would uninstall VirtualBox.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Apparently that option is not listed on the installer.